# Is running 2 batch processes on 2 separate threads possible and permissible with Intuit?

Tags: multithreading, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I wanted to tailor the application I am making which communicates with the quickbooks server and adds things like customers and check expenses and I wanted my application to be as efficient as possible regarding performance. For example, my intention was to have all customer additions (batch process) on one thread and all check expenses or bills (batch process) on another thread which is logically possible as the two procedures don't interfere and are not related to one another.

My question is would such a design approach be permissible by Intuit? I guess my concern is regarding any limitations on communication with their servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs site, the following throttling policy is mentioned.

**What are the throttling limits based on QB accounts, OAuth client, and RealmId at any given time?**

***EDIT*** Following line is not valid anymore. [FAQ](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq) page is updated.

Apart from an upper limit set that ensures no more than 10 requests in progress at any given time;

***EDIT***

we have a throttling policy across all IDS apis to permit 500 requests/minute per AuthId and per RealmId. The policy permits 200 requests/minute per AuthId for reports endpoints.

**Ref** - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq

So, if you follow the above throttling limit then parallel processing using multiple threads is not an issue.

PN - You can't create multiple name entities ( ex - Vendor, Employee and Customer) using parallel threads. Service puts a lock across these 3 entities to ensure an unique name is getting used while creating a new entity.

Thanks

Comment: Manas as you mentioned according to throttling policy no more than 10 requests in progress at any given time. Is one batch service request considered a single request? Also when you say 10 requests in progress at any given time, is that according to any identity such as per application or per realm id and auth id? Thanks

Comment: Batch is considered as a single request. For ex - 
https://e2e.qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/v3/company/1019711326/batch?requestid=123456& [ in the end of the URL we append a requestID to identify the batch].

Comment: There are some recent changes in the throttling policy. I will re-check the first part (10 reqs at any given time) with dev team and update in this post. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mohsin, the first line (Apart from an upper limit set that ensures no more than 10 requests in progress at any given time) is no longer valid. We have changed this in the FAQ page as well. Updating this post.

Comment: Hi Manas, thanks for your quick response. When you say the "no more than 10 requests in progress at any given time" is no longer valid, does that mean we can have multiple requests possibly exceeding 10 at any given time or does that mean that generally multiple requests at any given time are not permitted anymore? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You don't need to consider that old "10 requests in progress" policy anymore. Only applicable throttling limit is "500 requests/minute per AuthId and per RealmId for general IDS endpoints". You can use multiple threads with the above restrictions.